# php query result in html option

Tags: php, html, html-select

Why do I get a white row and not the value?

```
<select name="select">
    <?php                    
    $connessione = mysql_connect('localhost' , 'root', '') or die("Impossibile connettersi: " .mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("musica",$connessione);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artisti_preferiti");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        ?><option value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['cognome'];?></option> 
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: What does print_r($row) show?

Comment: i must show value of 'cognome' field of table artisti_preferiti

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: it seems to me the while loop will never end or am i seeing that wrong.

Comment: @NicolaCambara - that doesn't answer it either. Can you post the exact output from `print_r($row)`?

Comment: @user2997718 - `mysql_fetch_array()` will get the next record on every iteration of the loop, and will return a boolean false when it runs out of records.

Comment: ligabue is the exact output i should have.
sorry but i'm not english and sometimes i don't understand right

Comment: Add `print_r($row)` to your loop. What does it print out?

Comment: Or try `SELECT nome,cognome FROM artisti_preferiti` as your query

Comment: I would also add: 1) turn on error reporting, 2) give us the source result of the request (in your browser, while viewing this page do _right-click_ -> **view source**) or simply put, give us the output of $row

Comment: i added it between while and option in the loop and i didn't get output

Comment: how i can turn on error reporting?

Comment: You may need to pass DB connection to your query. Try `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artisti_preferiti",$connessione);` which I tested this with your code, and it worked. @NicolaCambara

Comment: it doesn't work @Fred-ii-

Comment: I posted something below that you can use, where I **fully and successfully tested** it before posting it, so if it does not work, then check all your settings. @NicolaCambara

Comment: i don't know what i can check, in other pages query worked right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this being a DB connection issue, where I **successfully tested** this.

Consider the following:

Sidenote: Make sure that your settings are correct, including the DB name, and colum names.

DB connection file: (db_connect.php)

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = 'xxx';

$mysqli = mysql_connect("$mysql_hostname", "$mysql_username", "$mysql_password");

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}

?>
```

PHP (example.php)

```
<select name="select">
<?php

include 'db_connect.php';

    mysql_select_db("musica",$mysqli);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artisti_preferiti",$mysqli);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        ?><option value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['cognome'];?></option> 
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

**On a final note**, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Do consider using `mysqli_*` with prepared statements or PDO.

---

### EDIT

### MySQLi_* version

Sidenote: It is best using column names instead of `SELECT *` --- i.e.: `SELECT nome, cognome`

DB connection file: (db_connect_mysqli.php)

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';

$mysqli = new mysqli("$mysql_hostname", "$mysql_username", "$mysql_password","$mysql_dbname");

if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
}

?>
```

PHP (example_mysqli.php)

```
<select name="select">
    <?php

include 'db_connect_mysqli.php';

$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM artisti_preferiti");


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        ?><option value="<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['cognome'];?></option> 
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: the dropdown menu is still empty and i didn't get errors.
this is the table in phpmyadmin if it can be useful:
http://i.imgur.com/gt21NkA.jpg
i've inserted this row in another page and connection works

Comment: It should work. Are you 100% certain that there is data in that table, and the columns? @NicolaCambara

Comment: And did you use both my codes **exactly** as I did it? Because like I said, I fully tested this. I never give answers, unless I'm 100% certain they work, believe me.  @NicolaCambara

Comment: yes, the only thing is that the second code is in a html page!

Comment: What do you mean in an html page? That page wouldn't have `.html` as the extension, would it? @NicolaCambara

Comment: Ok, you need to rename that file to `registrazione.php` @NicolaCambara `.html` will not process PHP.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. You want to use the `.html` file you gave me as a link, to work with your posted PHP code? @NicolaCambara if so, you need to do some modifications to it, and give it a `.php` extension. I don't know what you're trying to do here. If something else worked before, than you need to do exactly what you did there also.

Comment: now i must go out, tomorrow i'll explain you, thanks for the help

Comment: i didn't work in php for a long time, in other pages i used html pages where forms calls php file...
i forgot that in this case i have to use directly a php file, so now it works, thanks a lot my friend @Fred

Comment: You're welcome @NicolaCambara Glad it worked out. If you want to close the question properly, you can click the white checkmark that is beside my answer, till it turns green. Cheers my friend!

Answer (score 0):

I changed your script so that we can debug

```
<?php
$lnk = mysql_connect('localhost' , 'root', '') or die("Impossibile connettersi: " .mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("musica",$lnk);
$q = 'SELECT nome,cognome FROM artisti_preferiti';
$result = mysql_query($q,$lnk);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) $rows[$row['nome']] = $row['cognome'];
/* show us this!! */
print_r($rows);
?>
<select name="select"><?php
  foreach ($rows as $nome => $cognome) {
    echo "<option value='$nome'>$cognome</option>";
  }
?></select>
```

Comment: whit this, near the dropdown empty I have this:
$cognome) { echo ""; } ?>

Comment: was this the print_r output?
if not, how i can see it?

Comment: my bad, use `var_dump` on `$numRows` and `$rows`. **Var dump** will tell us what the variable is as well as what it contains. Rewrite my script and tell us all what the output becomes

Comment: if i write var_dump($numRows) or $rows i didn't get something.
how i can save the output?